# Poisson regression and prediction

Tags: r, predictive-models, poisson-distribution

I am studying R language and statistics and facing a problem of using predict function in R on Poisson model.

I want to find lambda for a Poisson model and then use lambda to calculate the probability of Y=0.

Does predict(object="poisson regression", type= "response") give me the lambda? or log(lambda)?

Thank you

Comment: It provides an estimate for $E(Y| X = x)$.

Comment: @MichaelM: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it.